# Is there a way to integrate my own custom tools into the Processing toolbox in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Is there a way to integrate my own custom tools into the Processing toolbox in QGIS? I believe I have found where to strategically hack the stock processing scripts to ensure it picks up my custom provider (python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py) but I can't figure out if there's a less kludgy way to register things.

I can't find any tutorials or anything so hoping that someone has either done this or can walk me through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing provides example code for a new algorithm provider. It's located in the processing folder inside your home directory, e.g. on my machine:

```
C:\Users\anita\.qgis2\python\plugins\processing\algs\exampleprovider
```

Based on these example files, you can build your own plugin which can contain as many new algorithms as you want.

Comment: Thanks. I found the example provider code but hadn't noticed the plugin element. This is exactly what I needed. Would be good to add some documentation on this. Maybe I'll do this when I have some free time.

Comment: I didn't see neither the 'example provider' in the list of provider available in qgis 2.8.1. When I run the command processing.Processing.providers, I don't see the exempleprovider in the list. I try to put on .qgis2\python\plugins\processing. \algs\exampleprovider, on .qgis2\python\ but it doesn't work. Why am I missing ?

Comment: I just found this qa.  Did you ever find out what the preferred way is to deploy and register your custom provider with QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post with an accepted answer, however I could not find a solution for newer versions of QGIS.  As of QGIS 2.14+ there are two main techniques to create a new plugin that adds its functionality as Processing algorithms:

> - Creating a plugin that adds an algorithm provider: This options is    more complex, but provides more flexibility.
> - Creating a plugin that contains a set of processing scripts: The    simplest solution, you just need a set of Processing script files.

This and more details can be found in the [documentation](http://create%20a%20new%20plugin%20that%20adds%20its%20functionality%20as%20Processing%20algorithms.).