# How to see the 'example provider' in processing toolbox of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I would like to create my own provider with the processing toolbox. I see the example provider in my folder C:\QgisWien\bin...\algs\ExampleProvider.

It seems to be a good start but unfortunately, I don't see the example provider in the processing toolbox.

I see this post : [Is there a way to integrate my own custom tools into the Processing toolbox in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155832/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-my-own-custom-tools-into-the-processing-toolbox-in-q/155840#155840)

I try to copy the folder ExampleProvider to my qgis plugins path but nothing.

I have Windows se7en and qgis wien installed.

Answer (score 1):

1) add the ExampleProvider folder in the qgis plugins ;

2) fix the path of the module in the different python files in order that the import does correctly.
 (one module seems to point to C:\QGISPATH\bin...\algs\ExampleProvider) ;

3) activate the plugin in the plugin manager.

And now, the Example aglorithms provider appears in my processing toolbox.