# Adding custom processing provider into QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to add a new processing algorithm provider into QGIS 2.18. In the picture below there are GDAL/OGR, GRASS GIS, etc. I want to add a provider called My Provider.

[image]

So I read the doc here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/processing.html
and saw:

[image]

So I followed:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then I reopened QGIS and installed the plugin, but no new provider appears. I read this thread: [How to see the 'example provider' in processing toolbox of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164189/how-to-see-the-example-provider-in-processing-toolbox-of-qgis). But this looks like this is for version 2.8, my exampleprovider is located in QGIS_2_18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\exampleprovider and I dont see which import is pointing to the wrong file.

What should I modify to make my provider appear in the processing toolbox?

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to add a new provider from your plugin?

Answer (score 3):

For create a custom processing provider into **QGIS 2.18**,all your steps is correct.
When create a provider,this not show by default,for example.

I created this :

[image]

save it :

[image]

but the new empty algorithm not show :

[image]

you need activate your plugin :

[image]

and click in "enable additional provider" in the bottom.

[image]

In the new dialog you can show your new provider:

[image]

And click "**activate**" checkbox for show it.

[image]

And enjoy!

**tested in QGIS 2.18**